# Eclipse (GUI) , giving a input and getting output from a program in the same window

Tags: java, eclipse

I created a small Window based Application in Eclipse. I have created a jtextfield and when I enter input and hit submit, it should show the output in the same window as the text area. What am I doing wrong? [The window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j68k0.png)

```
 import java.util.*;
 import java.lang.String;

 class ParenthesisMatching
 {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<String> stk = new Stack<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter expression");
        String exp = scan.next();        
        if(isValid(exp))
            System.out.println("matched");
        else System.out.println("unmatched");

    }

    public static boolean isValid(String s) {
        HashMap<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
        map.put('(', ')');
        map.put('[', ']');
        map.put('{', '}');

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char curr = s.charAt(i);

            if (map.keySet().contains(curr)) {
                stack.push(curr);
            } else if (map.values().contains(curr)) {
                if (!stack.empty() && map.get(stack.peek()) == curr) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return stack.empty();
    }  
 }
```

When I enter an expression, it says, "Matched and unmatched." It should also show the debugging info from the expression by printing in the window.

This is the code in the Application Window

Comment: Where in the window is the output supposed to appear? Do you have a JLabel or JTextArea?

Comment: Also, where is the code that creates the window? And where is the event handler for the button?

Comment: No,I dont have any Jlabel or JtextArea...I dont know how to perform action  for it. and I have Updated the code for Window Apllication.

Comment: I still don't see the code which creates your JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

After you create the JFrame which contains your widgets for input (a JLabel, a JEditText, and a JButton), you need to add a JLabel or a JTextArea where you can put the output. Then you use the appropriate methods of JLabel or JTextArea, such as setText() to show the output. For details on how to do this, I suggest doing a google search. In particular, you should check out any hits you get in the Oracle Java Tutorials.